# How to compare coefficients within the same multiple regression model?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

As the titles states, I would like to compare two coefficients in my multiple regression model but I'm not quite sure how.

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       68.9483    29.7439   2.318 0.024493 *  
Shots.PG          -0.5074     1.4696  -0.345 0.731334    
Shots.OT.PG        7.4992     3.1410   2.388 0.020707 *  
Dribbles.PG        0.6081     0.8121   0.749 0.457401    
Fouled.PG         -0.9856     0.8783  -1.122 0.267031    
Offsides.PG        1.0520     3.0728   0.342 0.733477    
Tackles.PG         0.2705     0.6721   0.402 0.689016    
Fouls.PG          -0.4230     0.7893  -0.536 0.594329    
Ints.PG            0.3414     0.5962   0.573 0.569451    
Shots.Allowed.PG  -3.3604     0.8063  -4.167 0.000119 ***
```

Above are the results I've obtained. At first glance I thought it was interesting Shots OT has double the impact of Shots Allowed but I see that their standard errors are significantly different so that worries me.

How would I go about comparing these two values?

Using linear.hypothesis() I get:

Linear hypothesis test

```
Hypothesis:
Shots.OT.PG  + 2 Shots.Allowed.PG = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: Points ~ Shots.PG + Shots.OT.PG + Dribbles.PG + Fouled.PG + Offsides.PG + 
    Tackles.PG + Fouls.PG + Ints.PG + Shots.Allowed.PG

  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     52 4488.5                           
2     51 4484.2  1    4.2107 0.0479 0.8277
```

How do I interpret this? Does this mean they are not different due to its large P Value. I am trying to find out whether or not the Shots OT has a larger effect on the Points total than the Shots Allowed PG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `md1` is `lm` model. You could use `linear.hypothesis` from `car` package. Test

```
linear.hypothesis(md1, "Shots.OT.PG = -2*Shots.Allowed.PG")
```

If your p-value is greater than 0.05 you could not reject the Null Hypothesis, in this case, in absolute values, Shots.OT.PG coefficient is not different from the double of Shots.Allowed.PG coefficient.

Comment: Hey, I added my output for that in the body. Can you help me interpret that?

Comment: See the edit, you do not reject the null

Comment: But why would we double the Shots.Allowed.PG? Shouldn't we just check the difference between the actual values?

Comment: It depends on your hypothesis, see the OP.

Comment: Alright, and in the event we are able to reject the null hypothesis, we'll be able to see that they are in fact different. I dont know if that helps me make the inference I'm trying to make. When I look at the difference in slopes, it seems like Shots.OT.PG is twice and significant.. since we aren't able to reject the null hypothesis, does that mean they are most likely equally significant?

Comment: To see if they are different, in this case, you could simple do `linear.hypothesis(md1, "Shots.OT.PG = Shots.Allowed.PG")`

Comment: So lets say the P Value of that output is less than 0.05, would that mean we could make the conclusion that Shots OT are twice as significant as Shots Allowed? If not, is there any way to make that conclusion?

Comment: The test compares the coefficients values. For the second you ca compare p-values, but it is not really interesting if both are significant. Just compare absolute coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The sofware you use should let you test for contrasts.

Alvernatively, if your model is $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X2 + ... + remainder$, and you want to test $ H: \beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0 $, you can parametrized the model as $$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (X_1 + X_2) + (\beta_2 - \beta_1) X2 + ...remainder$$ 
and check the coefficient of $X_2$ in the second regression. But check if you can test contrast with the software you are using.

Comment: How would you test such a model in R?